# function not defined error and how no-wrap in head solves it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function in my `<head>`

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    function shout(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

And a button in the `<body>`

but I am getting `function shout not defined` .Why?I am using Firefox 25.

SO has many similar questions and I have tried all but no help.Except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534666/javascript-function-not-defined-error-syntax) one,which might solve my problem.I didn't get what the answer is talking about.Please anyone elaborate what he is talking about as the two **fiddles** ,in answer as well as the question are exactly same ,except some property changes on the leftside bar: `onload` and `No wrap-in <head>`

Or what might be the problem?

Comment: Please create fiddle and post here

Comment: line 1: function{ should be function() {

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including jQuery causes standard JavaScript to stop functioning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892246/including-jquery-causes-standard-javascript-to-stop-functioning)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is `visible` in it **enclosure** that is the `document.ready`. If you move function out side `document.ready` then it will accessible in global scope.

```
function shout(msg)
{
      alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is defined inside an anonymous function, so it's name is limited to that scope. If you're trying to access it from the `onclick` attribute of a button that won't work, because names there look in the global scope.

You have two solutions:

One is to define the function outside `$(document).ready()`, so it will be in the global scope.

The other is to bind your click handler using jQuery rather than an inline attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#somebutton").click(function() {
        shout("Button was clicked");
    });

    function shout(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function {
    shout('message');
});

function shout(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is wrapped inside a parent function. The scope inside the function is not available outside of it.

Separate it instead -

```
function shout(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

$('document').ready(function{
    shout('AWESOME');    
});
```